# Draw a line or a series of lines and get the total length of the lines combined?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I hope I can explain my idea clearly enough so you can help me figure it out.

[image]

Let´s say I click start and the program starts "recording" mouse events, then I click and create a point, click somewhere else and create another point, when the second point is created a line is drawn connecting those two points, and so on until I create the last point I desire and click STOP, and then I get in return the length of the lines combined.

How hard is it to accomplish this in Python? There are libraries that can help me implement something like this?

Is there a way to do this without the points at all? Just click and then click again and a line is drawn and so on?

Comment: Take a look on `Canvas` (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm).

Comment: To get the length, especially, you're going to need the points. Here's some more [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html) on `tkinter` library's `Canvas` widgets which have a `create_line()` method. As far as length goes, for 2D I'd suggest using [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) which would make calculating it pretty easy (by passing it the difference between coordinates, x0-x1 and y0-y1, of the two points making up each line segment).

Comment: Since it's your code that's creating the lines, why not just calculate the length of each line as it's being drawn, then add all the lengths together?

Comment: Thank you guys, I will take a further look into Canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no additional library needed. You can simply bind `<Button-1>` to an event and calculate distance by using `event.x` and `event.y`.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

root = Tk()
root.configure(background='DeepSkyBlue4')

class DrawLine:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, width=500, height=500,bg="white")
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self._move(e.x,e.y))
        self.previous_pos = None
        self.total_length = 0
        self.t = Label(master, text=f"Total Length: {self.total_length} pixels",font=('Arial',12),pady=5,bg="DeepSkyBlue4",fg="white")
        self.t.pack()
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.random_position()

    def _move(self,new_x,new_y):
        self.canvas.create_oval(new_x + 5, new_y + 5, new_x - 5, new_y - 5, width=0, fill='red')
        if self.previous_pos:
            old_x, old_y = self.previous_pos
            self.canvas.create_line(old_x, old_y, new_x, new_y, width=2)
            self.total_length += ((new_x - old_x) ** 2 + (new_y - old_y) ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
            self.t.config(text=f"Total Length: {round(self.total_length,2)} pixels")
        self.previous_pos = (new_x, new_y)

    def random_position(self):
        self._move(randint(0,500),randint(0,500))
        root.after(1000,self.random_position)

DrawLine(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Henry, your example really helped me to have an idea how to get this done.